# AWS CodeCommit prevent merge until successful build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I'm using an AWS Lambda function to kick off a build in AWS CodeBuild when a Pull Request is created or updated in AWS CodeComimit, which is working well.

However, I'd like to be able to prevent the merging of that Pull Request in to the master branch of the repository, until the latest build for that PR has completed successfully.

Does anyone know if there's a way that can be done in AWS? E.g. so that the Merge button is disabled or not available, like when not enough approvers have been obtained?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking into this myself and from what I understand, it is currently not possible to *directly* create this rule, but I think it should be doable with a different approach.

Instead of requiring a custom rule that disables merging (which doesn't exist today), you could make it so that the PR requires review from a specific IAM user. With that, you could probably use a fixed "build" user, and fire an automatic approval request for the PR once the build finishes successfully. This will in turn "approve" that rule in the PR and allow it to be merged after the build succeeds.

Since approval can be done via the CLI interface, I'm sure it should also be possible via API. For example, you could use [this API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_UpdatePullRequestApprovalState.html) to automatically mark any given PR as approved by the calling user, then ensure the service that is calling it is the same user registered in the "build" approval template.

Besides the HTTP WebApi, there are also other ways to call into these CodeCommit actions, like the AWS SDK library (C# example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CodeCommit/).